# Displaying a video file using MPMoviePlayerViewController on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

I'm trying to open a video file on a server.

It works fine on < 6.0 using this code:

```
 NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[[[self.campArray objectAtIndex:button.tag]valueForKey:@"images"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"imageURL"]];
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
[self presentModalViewController:self.moviePlayer animated:YES];
[self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
[self.moviePlayer release];
```

but when trying running this code on a device which has iOS 6, the modal view presented and then after 1 sec it closes. It'd not crushing... the player modal view just closes...
I read about this and also added `@property (strong,nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer;` but it's still not working...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use presentViewController method in iOS 6.0 to presenting a view controller. presentModalViewController is deprecated in ios 6.0.

Comment: Does not work for me. I still get the crash saying " Uncaught exception: Attempting to begin a modal transition from <UINavigationController: 0x1edc4060> to <MPMoviePlayerViewController: 0x1eddda70> while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed"

Comment: @RishabhTayal you are calling the method in viewdidload of your viewcontroller (this happens when the viewController hasn't appear yet)...you need to wait until that viewcontroller has appeared (viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear) so you can present a new view controller